# mysqldump: How to ensure order of tables content in generated txt files

Tags: mysql

I run mysqldump on a before and after picture of database before tests

```
mysqldump --no-create-info --no-create-db  --tab=/data/tmp/db1 statsdb
```

and after tests

```
mysqldump --no-create-info --no-create-db  --tab=/data/tmp/db2 statsdb
```

So then i do a diff

```
diff --brief /data/tmp/db1 /data/tmp/db2
Files /data/tmp/db1/details.txt and 
/data/tmp/db2/details.txt differ
```

The trouble is that it results in the txt files, despite having same data created in the db1 and db2 directories do not display the lines in the same order.

Is there a way to force them to sort correctly? Here is the differing files for the record

```
[root@server ~]# cat /data/tmp/db2/enm_network_element_details.txt
2018-09-26      1       RNC     18.Q1-V.12.40   1       1       1       0     
0
2018-09-26      1       MGW     17A-C.1.267     15      15      15      15      
0
2018-09-26      1       ERBS    17.Q4-J.1.160   480     480     475     480     
479
2018-09-26      1       SGSN-MME        16A-CP09        14      14      14      
14      0
2018-09-26      1       MTAS    MTAS-1.5        10      10      10      10      
0
2018-09-26      1       SIU02   17A     56      56      56      54      0
2018-09-26      1       Router6672      R17B-GA 1       1       1       0       
0
2018-09-26      1       RBS     18.Q1-U.4.750   350     350     350     350      
0
2018-09-26      1       RNC     17B-V.9.1240    1       1       1       1       
0
2018-09-26      1       Router6672      R18A-GA 104     104     104     104     
0
2018-09-26      1       MINI-LINK-Indoor        M16A-TN-5.4FP-L 18      18      
18      5       5
2018-09-26      1       ERBS    18.Q1-J.1.220   1       0       0       0       
0
2018-09-26      1       EPG     16B-R13C        6       6       6       6       
0
2018-09-26      1       MINI-LINK-6352  M17B-6352-2.8   15      15      15      
15      0
2018-09-26      1       MINI-LINK-Indoor        M17.Q4-TN-6.1-L 41      41      
41      4       4
2018-09-26      1       MINI-LINK-Indoor        M17A-TN-6.0-LH- 9       9       
9       9       9
2018-09-26      1       TCU02   17A     56      56      56      54      0
2018-09-26      1       DSC     17B-R1A 10      10      10      10      0
2018-09-26      1       RadioNode       17B-R6A19       550     550     550     
550     0
2018-09-26      1       RadioNode       17Q4-R25A12     160     160     160     
160     158

[root@server~]# cat /data/tmp/db1/enm_network_element_details.txt
2018-09-26      1       RadioNode       17Q4-R25A12     160     160     160     
160     158
2018-09-26      1       RadioNode       17B-R6A19       550     550     550     
550     0
2018-09-26      1       RNC     18.Q1-V.12.40   1       1       1       0       
0
2018-09-26      1       MGW     17A-C.1.267     15      15      15      15      
0
2018-09-26      1       ERBS    17.Q4-J.1.160   480     480     475     480     
479
2018-09-26      1       MTAS    MTAS-1.5        10      10      10      10      
0
2018-09-26      1       SIU02   17A     56      56      56      54      0
2018-09-26      1       Router6672      R17B-GA 1       1       1       0       
0
2018-09-26      1       SGSN-MME        16A-CP09        14      14      14      
14      0
2018-09-26      1       RNC     17B-V.9.1240    1       1       1       1       
0
2018-09-26      1       RBS     18.Q1-U.4.750   350     350     350     350     
0
2018-09-26      1       Router6672      R18A-GA 104     104     104     104     
0
2018-09-26      1       MINI-LINK-Indoor        M16A-TN-5.4FP-L 18      18      
18      5       5
2018-09-26      1       EPG     16B-R13C        6       6       6       6       
0
2018-09-26      1       ERBS    18.Q1-J.1.220   1       0       0       0       
0
2018-09-26      1       MINI-LINK-6352  M17B-6352-2.8   15      15      15      
15      0
2018-09-26      1       MINI-LINK-Indoor        M17.Q4-TN-6.1-L 41      41      
41      4       4
2018-09-26      1       MINI-LINK-Indoor        M17A-TN-6.0-LH- 9       9       
9       9       9
2018-09-26      1       TCU02   17A     56      56      56      54      0
2018-09-26      1       DSC     17B-R1A 10      10      10      10      0
```

Comment: SQL tables do not have an intrinsic order because you can order the records when you query them. There is no point in comparing unordered sets.

Comment: Again, what problem does it cause that the items are in a different order in the two files? After importing these two files into any sql database, you can specify your own ordering of the resultset on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

The option "--order-by-primary" might be what you need.
Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-option-summary

Comment: Tried same but still get different orders in both files, edited question to show you what it looks like

Comment: Though they look exactly the same. What about sorting the txt files with sort command before running the diff? Or what about comparing the tables in SQL?